# AngularJS Passing Expressions Into Function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my angularJS I'm using `ng-repeat` to iterate through comments like so.

```
<li class="item block-size" ng-repeat="comment in comments" >
                    <div class="header">
                        <span class="count">{{$index + 1}}</span>
                        <span class="people">3 <i class="icon-user icon-large"></i></span>
                        <span class="comments">5 <i class="icon-comments-alt icon-large"></i></span>
                        <span class="open"><a href="#conversation-modal" role="button"  ng-click="commentPopup({{comment.comment_id}})" ><i class="icon-external-link icon-large"></i>Onions</a></span>
                    </div>
<li>
```

In `ng-click`, I am calling a function the controller called `commentPopup`, which is suppose to take the currents comment id. The problem is it does not work with expressions. The function looks like this:

```
$scope.commentPopup = function(comment_id) {

         alert(comment_id);

    };
```

If I do

```
commentPopup(1);
```

it works. But if I do

```
commentPopup({{comment.comment_id}})
```

I does not work. Can anyone else me how to pass the comment id into this function?

Comment: `commentPopup(comment.comment_id)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to pass along this data, try removing the `{{}}` so the call will just look like

```
ng-click="commentPopup(comment.comment_id)"
```

This should automatically fill in the comment id once it has compiled the template of the `ng-repeat`